# New Timeline Like Button Behavior

Tags: tabs, facebook-like

On the new style Page Tabs, the Like button no longer re-freshes the page. This breaks the existing workflow for "Like-gates", where the signed request is checked on the server. Like the page, page refreshes, boom - the tab now updates to the "Liked" state.

Will there be any kind of event fired when user clicks thew new Like button? Or is this kind of gating no longer possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto refresh timeline page when like button pressed on application?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9509173/auto-refresh-timeline-page-when-like-button-pressed-on-application)

Comment: Although this bug has been fixed and I've seen a number of bugs logged for this issue being resolved. I am still seeing this occur (and have had to log a bug this week) and actually increase across a number of our client's like gates this week. Is the page refresh after like button action going to be permanently removed? Or is this just one of those bugs that is reappearing? Bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/252051668220860?browse=search_4f69ffddcd0036480430140

Answer (score 0):

it's a bug that the page is not refreshing after being liked. Here's the bug reported:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/228778937218386?browse=search_4f500194bc1bd0293819428

However, I managed to do a workaround to detect if the page is still not using timeline by looking for an album called "Cover Photos" on the album list of that page. Here's a sample:

http://graph.facebook.com/-page_id-/albums?fields=name

You don't need a token unless the page isn't published yet.

The problem with this approach is that some pages still don't have cover picture yet, but it's the minority.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is now fixed by Facebook. See here:

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/228778937218386

So everyone can relax.