# Does anyone know a fix for the lack of page refresh on facebook timeline pages when liking?

Tags: facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New Timeline Like Button Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508624/new-timeline-like-button-behavior)

Timeline pages are going to be enforced for locations and brands as of 30th of March.

Problem is that if you have any application attached to a page that asks the user to "Like" the page before they can enter the competition or see exclusive content, previously the page would refresh when the like button was pressed, so revealing the next stage.

Right now this does not happen when liking a new timeline page from the application view. Therefore the user needs to manually refresh the page to see the content.

Does anyone know of a workaround to this behaviour, as this will break many applications we know of.

Thanks for any help you may have!

UPDATE:

We have found that this is listed as a submitted bug to Facebook. Not sure how long they will take to change it.

Comment: I was wondering the exact same thing. I'm not sure whether its just a bug as it's not 30th March yet or Facebook are trying to do away with like and reveal tabs. There may be a way around with it by using ajax to check like status but I haven't had a chance to check it out fully yet.

Comment: This is the bug url, for reference: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/228778937218386?browse=search_4f5151fc03e4e2953631538